# Import emails from Outlook 2013 with exchange server with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Importing emails from Outlook 2013 to Excel 2013 works with home desktop. Outlook 2013 is connected to SMTP/POP server.

The same code does not work in my office. Outlook 2013 is connected to exchange server.

**Error at .Senderemailaddress**

```
Option Explicit
Dim n As Long
Sub Get_data()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Date1, Date2
Date1 = "01/26/2017"

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNS.PickFolder
n = 2
Call Get_Emails(olFolder, Date1)

Set olNS = Nothing
Set olFolder = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
End Sub

Sub Get_Emails(olfdStart As Outlook.MAPIFolder, Date1)
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olObject As Object
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Recivedt As Date

For Each olObject In olfdStart.Items
    If TypeName(olObject) = "MailItem" Then

        If olObject.ReceivedTime <= Date1 Then
            n = n + 1
            Set olMail = olObject
             'Sno
            Cells(n, 1) = n
             'Universal id
            Cells(n, 2) = olMail.ConversationID
             'Email id

            'Getting debug error here as not supported.
            Cells(n, 3) = olMail.SenderEmailAddress '**

             'Date and time workings
            Cells(n, 4) = olMail.ReceivedTime
             'Size
            Cells(n, 6) = olMail.Size

             'Subject
            Cells(n, 7) = olMail.Subject

        End If
    End If
Next
Set olMail = Nothing
Set olFolder = Nothing
Set olObject = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: And what is the relevant snippet of your code? Which line raises the exception? What is the **exact** exception?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko it's tagged with VBA, so there wouldn't be an *exception* (that would be a .net thing) but a "run-time error". But yeah, definitely agree - there's nothing to be done with this question without any code and additional information.

Comment: The exceptions would be standard COM exceptions - OOM does not know or care whether it is being used from VBA. Net, Delphi, or C++. Exceptions are definitely not .Net specific. VBA (which is COM based) just has a funny way of handling them using "on error..." etc.

Comment: Hello Experts....Question is basically on Excel vba which works fine at home but not in my office as posted my qustion this may be outlook 2013 is connected to exchange server... There is no option to attatch file showing the code....please help.                                                            ========================================================

Answer (score 1):

Cross posting is good but always mention the links in both the threads.

[Importing outlook emails to excel in 2013 version.](http://chandoo.org/forum/threads/importing-outlook-emails-to-excel-in-2013-version.32930/)

Just tested with Excel/Outlook2013 connected to Exchange Server & didn't replicate the issue.

Are u getting error on very first email or in a specific email??

However Check with below changes.

```
Function Get_Sender_Address(oMsg As Outlook.MailItem) As String
Dim oExUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser, oAddType As Outlook.AddressEntry

Set oAddType = oMsg.Sender

If oAddType.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry Then
    Set oExUser = oAddType.GetExchangeUser
        Get_Sender_Address = oExUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
Else
    Get_Sender_Address = oMsg.SenderEmailAddress
End If

Set oAddType = Nothing:    Set oExUser = Nothing

End Function
```

&

```
Cells(n, 3) = Get_Sender_Address(olMail) 'olMail.SenderEmailAddress
```